# Asking about a cyclic $D$-module isomorphic to $\frac{D}{(p^k)}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I am sorry if the post is duplicated, I have not been able to find the following result:

> Let $D$ be a principal ideal domain, let $p\in D$ be an irreducible element. Let $M$ be a cyclic $D$-module isomorphic to $\frac{D}{(p^k)}$ for some integer $k\geq 1$.
>
> > Prove that $ann_{M}(p)$ is a vector space over $\frac{D}{(p)}$ with dimension 1.

Could you give me a proof or a source where to find it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu:M\to pM$ denote the multiplication by $p$; we have to prove $\operatorname{Ker}\mu\cong D/pD$.
By third isomorphism theorem we have an exact sequence of $D$-modules:
$${0}\to D/pD\to D/p^kD\xrightarrow\mu pD/p^kD\to\{0\}$$
which proves the assertion.